# Coin count consistency through game

Tags: python

I'm learning python through Learn Python the Hard Way. I'm on lesson 35 where you write a short "game".

From the lesson I'm making my own little game just to expand my understanding of this part of the course. I'm trying to have coins that are used to buy things, get picked up, dropped, etc. I can't figure out how to have the coin count stay consistent  (i.e. if you buy something, it takes away x amount of coins, and the next time you go to buy something you also only have the remainder).

Example of part of the code below. I've tried everything I know how to do (which obviously is not much at this point!) but the coin count always resets when the function is called again (after buying a sword or shield).

```
def bazaar1():
print "\"Welcome to the Hyrule Bazaar\", the storekeeper mumbles."
print "What would you like to buy? We have:\n\nSwords (10c)\nShields (10c)\nBows (10c)\nArrows (10 for 10c)\n"

bazaar_c = raw_input("> ")
if "sword" in bazaar_c:
    print "You got the Hero Sword!\n"
    bazaar1()
elif "shield" in bazaar_c:
    print "You got the Hyrule Shield.\n"
    bazaar1()
elif "leave" in bazaar_c:
    hyruletown()
elif "exit" in bazaar_c:
    hyruletown()
else:
    print "Sorry, that's not an option.\n"
    bazaar1()
```

Comment: You aren't showing any code that actually stores the current coin count.

Comment: chepner: right, I know. Everything I tried didn't work so I erased it. Could add it if it makes it easier to solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have some kind of player state variable to pass to each of your 'zone' functions. It could be as simple as a dict:

```
player_data = {
 'hearts': 3,
 'coins': 10,
 'items': []
}
```

Then pass it to each of your functions:

```
def bazaar1(player_data):
  print "\"Welcome to the Hyrule Bazaar\", the storekeeper mumbles."
  print '\n'.join(["What would you like to buy? We have:\n",
                   'Swords (10c)',
                   'Shields (10c)',
                   'Bows (10c)',
                   'Arrows (10 for 10c)'])

  bazaar_c = raw_input("> ")
  if "sword" in bazaar_c:
    if player_data['coins'] >= 10:
        print "You got the Hero Sword!\n"
        player_data['inventory'].append('sword')
        player_data['coins'] -= 10
    else:
        print "You don't have enough coins"
    bazaar1(player_data)
#...
```

Comment: Thanks Chad. Does the player state stay consistent through all of the functions when added as you did above? i.e. if they go through to the next thing, drop a bunch of coins or something, the player data is 'global'?

Answer (score -1):

```
again=True

Total=0

Wrongs=0

Corrects=0


Total_bags=0

Wrong_bags=0

Correct_bags=0

coins=['1p','2p','5p','10p','20p','50p','£1','£2']

bag_value=[1.00,1.00,5.00,5.00,10.00,10.00,20.00,20.00]

bag_weight=[356,356,325,325,250,160,175,120]

coins_len=len(coins)

Master_list=list()

CoinCount_list=list()

Tile_list=['Name','Coin','Weight','Accurate']

Master_list.append(Tile_list)

with open("Master.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write("{}".format(Master_list))

while True:
again=True


what=input("Would you like to add a bag")


if what=='Yes':

    name=input("What is your name")

    CoinCount_list.append(name)

    with open("CoinCount.txt","w") as f: 
        f.write("{}".format(CoinCount_list))



    Percent=Corrects*Wrongs/100



    CoinCount_list.append(Percent)

    with open("CoinCount.txt","w") as f: 
        f.write("{}".format(CoinCount_list))

    Percent=0

    Wrongs=0

    Corrects=0 

    while again:
```

## Coin

```
        coin_input=input("What type of coin do you have")
        for i in range (0,coins_len):






            if coin_input==coins[i]:
                Coin=coins[i]
                valid=input("That is valid, is that what you wanted")

                if valid=="Yes":


                    CoinCount_list.append(coins[i])

                    with open("CoinCount.txt","w") as f: 
                        f.write("{}".format(CoinCount_list))
```

## Weight

```
                    weight=int(input("What is the weight of the bag"))


                    CoinCount_list.append(weight)

                    with open("CoinCount.txt","w") as f: 
                        f.write("{}".format(CoinCount_list))

                        if weight == bag_weight[i]:

                            Total_bags=Total_bags+1

                            again=input("Thank you would you like to add another bag")

                            CoinCount_list.append('Correct')

                            with open("CoinCount.txt","w") as f: 
                                f.write("{}".format(CoinCount_list))

                            Total=bag_value[i]+Total
                            Correct_bags=Correct_bags+1

                            Corrects=Corrects+1

                            if again== 'Yes':
                                a='b'



                            else:
                                again=False


                                Master_list.append(CoinCount_list)

                                with open("Master.txt","w") as f: 
                                    f.write("{}".format(Master_list))







                        elif weight > bag_weight[i]:
                            print("You have too many coins")

                            Wrong_bags=Wrong_bags+1
                            Total_bags=Total_bags+1

                            Wrongs=Wrongs+1



                        elif weight < bag_weight[i]:
                            print("You have too few coins")

                            Wrong_bags=Wrong_bags+1
                            Total_bags=Total_bags+1

                            Wrongs=Wrongs+1




    else:
        print("")
        print("  We have check",Total_bags," ")
        print(" ",Correct_bags,"Correctly")
        print(" ",Wrong_bags,"Incorrectly")
        print("  We have raised",Total," ")
        print("")
        with open("Master.txt") as f:
            rd=f.readlines()
        print (rd)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This code is Python, but the indentation and code is not clean.  Ex. your first code section ends with `while again:`, then it goes to the "Coin" section.  Please read [answer].  Also code only answers are not optimal.  Providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.